# Choosing the number of topics in topic modeling with multiple "elbows" in the coherence plot

Tags: topic-models, latent-dirichlet-alloc

When plotting the number of topics on the x-axis and the coherence score on the y-axis, I had expected to see an "elbow" (for example, [here](https://www.machinelearningplus.com/nlp/topic-modeling-gensim-python/#17howtofindtheoptimalnumberoftopicsforlda) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elbow_method_(clustering))).

In this case, however, the plot does not have a unique elbow, and instead of becoming flatter, the coherence score keeps increasing, as shown in the plot below:[image]

In such a scenario, how should the optimal number of topics be chosen?

I have used LDA (from gensim) for topic modeling.

Answer (score 0):

You should focus more on your pre-processing step, noise in is noise out. Moreover, a coherence score of < 0.6 is considered bad. Lastly, look at your y-axis - there's not much difference between 10 and 35 topics.